# Javascript - Detect a form button press

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button

I wrote some test code to see if i could detect the pressing of a form's submit button.

HTML

```
<form action="/pst" method="POST">
    Form
<input type="url" name="form_input">
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
                var submit = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
                submit.onclick = function() {
                    alert("Button pressed!");
                }
</script>
```

This does not work...
Also i have to report that the script is locaded inside the `<body>`.

Comment: You're setting `var submit` to the url input, not the submit button.  To get the submit button use `document.querySelector('input[type=submit]');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var submit = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
```

This will select the first input, of type = url, not the submit. This is because the url input is first in the DOM, before the submit input.

Target the element more accurately. Give it an ID or use a query like

```
document.querySelector('input[type=submit]');
```

Also, you should probably be listening in on the form's submission event, not the button's click event.

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', ...
```

Comment: In the last piece of code... what goes after the 'submit'?

Answer (score -3):

You are referencing the first `input` element in the document when you use an index of `0`, but you need to reference the second `input` element. It will work if you reference the correct element. You want index 1, not 0.

```js
var submit = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1];
submit.onclick = function() {
  alert("Button pressed!");
}
```

```html
<form action="/pst" method="POST">
    Form
  <input type="url" name="form_input">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

---

As you are just learning, it's appropriate to kill some bad habits before they settle in. `.getElementsByTagName()` certainly works, but it returns what is called a "live" node list which means that every time you use the variable referencing the list, the entire document must be scanned again to find the most up-to-date set of matching elements. As such, it should only be used in situations where elements are being dynamically added/removed from the document. Additionally, since you are only interested in one element, scanning the whole document for a set of elements, just to throw all but one of those references away is wasteful.

Instead, use more appropriate APIs, such as [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Next, instead of setting up your event handler with the `.onclick` property, use the more modern and robust [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) API, which allows you to register multiple event handlers for a single event.

Lastly, be aware that clicking a `submit` button actually triggers two events, the `click` event of the button itself and the `submit` event of the `form` element that the submit button is tied to. Usually, we want to tap into the `submit` event of the form.

Putting this all together:

```js
// Get a reference to the form
var form = document.querySelector("form");

// Set up a submit event handler
form.addEventListener("submit", function() {
  alert("Form Submitted!");
});

// Get a reference to the textbox
var textbox = document.querySelector("input[type='url']");

// Set up a input event handler (fires every time you type in the box)
textbox.addEventListener("input", function() {
  console.log("edit - new value is:" + this.value);
});
```

```html
<form action="/pst" method="POST">
    Form
  <input type="url" name="form_input">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This will break as soon as another input element is added to the form (which it almost definitely will), and you've not explained *why* this makes any difference.  A better solution is definitely to target the element more precisely, as per the answer from Utkanos.

Comment: @Archer I am working on an edit to more fully explain, but the answer is correct as it does explain why the current code is not working.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how you've improved the answer.  You've explained a lot of stuff but not the difference between [0] and [1], which is all that was previously wrong, and you've also given them code to handle an input value changing, which is nothing to do with what the OP is asking.

Comment: @Archer *Sorry, but I don't see how you've improved the answer.*  Ok, well I think  it's pretty clear what `[0]` and `[1]` do given that the OP is the one that supplied the indexing code in the first place. And, the `input` event was added as an *additional* example of event handling.

Comment: I see this as vastly over-complicating the issue whilst never giving a simple explanation of what the original problem was.  We disagree with each other and that just happens.  OP has a clear answer already, so I'll leave it at that :)